# Get HSV values of pixels on surface in pygame

Tags: pygame, rgb, hsv, pygame-surface

I set my webcam in pygame to use HSV color space. But pygame.Surface.get_at only returns the RGB-color values. Is there a method for reading the HSV values of pixels in pygame?

If not, what is the recommended way of converting all pixels colors to HSV in pygame?

Comment: Check this page : http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's [colorsys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html) module.

It contains a function [`rgb_to_hsv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html#colorsys.rgb_to_hsv) which you can use to convert the RGB values into HSV values.

Comment: Thank you. But i already used colorsys and also pygames pygame.Color.hsva to convert RGB to HSV values. It works, but the conversion is slow even though i work with small resolutions like 160x120.

Comment: OK. Maybe you want to try mathplotlib? It provides a [rgb_to_hsv](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv) function working on a numpy array. You could create such an array using pygame's `surfarray` module. Sorry but I can't test this myself at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @sloth. The rgb_to_hsv function of mathplotlib did the job:
rgb = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(image)
hsv = matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(rgb / 255.0)